# Select Image from Gallery Not Posting to App in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I am really new and been looking through a few tutorials on Android Studio to get some help to make a simple imageview that just picks an image from gallery and displays it on the page. I can get it click and pull up gallery but it wont display after choosing the image from gallery. I looked over a few tutorials and I dont see anything I am missing? Any help?

android manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="adamnate.ddproject" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission a
```

ndroid:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

MainActivity.xml

```
 package adamnate.ddproject;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.provider.MediaStore;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
ImageView imageToUpload;
Button bUploadImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     imageToUpload = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageToUpload);
     bUploadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bUploadImage);

    imageToUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
        }
    });
}





@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode ==11)
       imageToUpload.setImageURI(data.getData());
    }
 }
}
```

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageToUpload"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bUploadImage"
        android:text="Upload Image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
requestCode == 1
```

and not

```
requestCode == 11
```

because you put 1 on the requestCode param when you call startActivityForResult()

Comment: Wow. All that looking at was it. Thanks a lot that works now! Appreciated!